# Is there a problem in this BN form language?

Tags: formal-languages

I am working on a simple text query language.  I am using the SLY parser, which itself is an LR parser/shift-reduce parser.  I am running into problems with the following language specification, but I don't understand why.  All I'm trying to do is appropriately group logical statements involving the operators AND and OR (in which AND gets precedence over OR and the statements are left associative) and "words", which is basically anything other than "AND" or "OR".  The language is below.  What is the problem?

```
LOGICAL ::= <WORD> <OPERATOR> <WORD> 
        | <WORD> <OPERATOR> <LOGICAL>
        | <LOGICAL> <OPERATOR> <WORD>
        | <LOGICAL> <OPERATOR> <WORD>

OPERATOR ::= "AND"
            | "OR"

WORD ::= any string other than "AND" or "OR"
```

Also, for the record I don't know how to express "WORD" in a more formal way, so I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

That grammar has two problems.

1. It's ambiguous. You say that you want to give `AND` precedence over `OR` and make both operators left-associative, but your grammar does not reflect that goal since it does not distinguish `AND` from `OR` and it explicitly accepts both left- and right-associative parses:

   ```
   <WORD> <OPERATOR> <LOGICAL>    (* right associative *)
   <LOGICAL> <OPERATOR> <WORD>    (* left associative *)
   ```
2. On a more minor level, probably a typo, your third and fourth productions are identical.

It's possible that you have tried to fix the issue by using precedence declarations in your parser generator tool. Precedence declarations are not part of BNF, and incorrect precedence declarations are really a programming error, rather than an issue in parser theory.

If you have such a problem, you should probably ask a question on a programming site, such as StackOverflow, and comply with the usual rules of including a complete reproducible example. However, in the usual approach to using precedence to resolve parser ambiguity, it is important that you don't have explicit parser ambiguity, as above. Thus, a "traditional" precedence-augmented BNF grammar (as per the Dragon book) would look like this:

```
%left <OR>
%left <AND>

<LOGICAL> ::= <WORD>
          |   <LOGICAL> <OR> <LOGICAL>
          |   <LOGICAL> <AND> <LOGICAL>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your explicit use of <WORD> as a logical was unexpected, but after a bit of work the language no longer has conflicts and parses correctly.  Out of curiosity, was this question supposed to be asked on SO, not this site?  I am using a particular parser generating program, but I did want to ask more generally about the language itself.

Comment: @michael: the question "how do I translate a precedence-augmented grammar to BNF?" would certainly fit here. But "what's wrong with this SLY specification?" is a programming question.

Comment: As for `logical` being a `word`, that's logical, isn't it? It's the base case in a recursion. Also, if you were to allow parentheses, you'd add that as well: `logical: '(' logical ')'`. See any example of a BNF grammar for algebraic expressions.

Comment: Indeed.  I'm very new to formal languages, so using word as a logical was a bit of a surprise :-) And yes, my question was actually about the grammar itself, not the specific tool, although I realize I could have made that more clear.